# IIS app pool crashing with exception 0xc0000005

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

My app pool keeps crashing when I use a .net provider written by a third party. I'm not sure where to even begin to troubleshoot the issue.

I used Event Viewer to get the following information:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b96e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00052d94
Faulting process id: 0x162c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd8ad4f6ad757b
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 36661c3b-f6c8-11e1-830c-180373c0a6cd
```

```
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-09-04T19:39:17.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>26328</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>my computer</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
  <Data>w3wp.exe</Data> 
  <Data>7.5.7601.17514</Data> 
  <Data>4ce7a5f8</Data> 
  <Data>ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>6.1.7601.17514</Data> 
  <Data>4ce7b96e</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>00052d94</Data> 
  <Data>162c</Data> 
  <Data>01cd8ad4f6ad757b</Data> 
  <Data>c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>36661c3b-f6c8-11e1-830c-180373c0a6cd</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Well, "0xc0000005" could be an Memory Access Violation. Perhaps you cantact the third Party.
What type of Provider are you using there?

Comment: It works fine in IIS express but as soon as I deploy to IIS it crashes. Unify is the name of the company. SQLBase.

Comment: Did you try to deploy it to a local IIS (On the same Computer as the IIS Express)?
If not - you should try, if it crashes there - contact the Company. If it crashes not - check your prequisites on the target Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kindly check the account under which worker process w3wp.exe is running have read/write permissions of your hosting folder.(E.g. Inetpub)

Comment: I think that could be the issue. The provider assembly loads other assemblies that are used. The path to the additional assemblies is specified in an ini file. Maybe a permission issue on the other assemblies? This is all new to me so I'm not the best at troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: That was my issue. In a VM, the `DefautlAppPool` kept stopping out of nothing when a page was requested. Changed the App Pool identity and now it's working. Maybe someone messed up with the `Network Service` account permissions (the one used before) on this VM.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
In my code I had the following line of vb.net code:

```
Dim mPath as string = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

My whole ASP.NET crashed, because it can't access this folder at runtime.
Error handling doesn't work. Clr simply crashes.

Replacing this line by an existing directory solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it took me two days to find the solution. So even if this thread is almost three years old I post my answer. Maybe it helps someone else to save a lot of time.

I had to disable the cache feature in the web.config. I used the "caching" as well as the "staticContent" tag. Had to remove both.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but it was solved by manually deleting my MVC project's bin and obj folders.

Comment: Lol i can't just clear out my bin folder, it is where all my backend .dll files are located.

Comment: @HarveyLin Nothing important should be in your bin folder or any other "build" folder. That's for artifacts of the build process. If you are relying on these files being there, they need to be moved there by some script in the build process.

Comment: After installed debugging tools, I found the problem. It was a typo in one the the tables in one of my sql queries. Nothing to do with IIS, or permission in that case.